# How can I add a filled rectangle outside the boundary of the plot in place of the legend?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, label, fill

I have a dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
Indicators  Historical  Policies and action High    Policies and action Low
2015    50.625053   NaN NaN
2016    50.582576   NaN NaN
2017    51.292209   NaN NaN
2018    51.941135   NaN NaN
2019    52.035179   52.035179   51.998587
2020    NaN 49.548225   49.192943
2021    NaN 51.044943   50.036852
2022    NaN 51.859163   50.489466
2023    NaN 52.181097   50.664963
2024    NaN 52.503669   50.748202
2025    NaN 52.834307   50.791621
```

`df.to_dict()` is as shown:

```
{'Historical': {2015: 50.6250534,
  2016: 50.5825758,
  2017: 51.292208707843,
  2018: 51.9411345916894,
  2019: 52.0351792911552,
  2020: nan,
  2021: nan,
  2022: nan,
  2023: nan,
  2024: nan,
  2025: nan},
 'Policies and action High': {2015: nan,
  2016: nan,
  2017: nan,
  2018: nan,
  2019: 52.0351792911552,
  2020: 49.5482253492566,
  2021: 51.0449425357562,
  2022: 51.8591630733255,
  2023: 52.1810970660186,
  2024: 52.5036690312549,
  2025: 52.8343073895085},
 'Policies and action Low': {2015: nan,
  2016: nan,
  2017: nan,
  2018: nan,
  2019: 51.9985870414207,
  2020: 49.1929429878652,
  2021: 50.036851875037,
  2022: 50.4894655321311,
  2023: 50.6649626706684,
  2024: 50.7482020284128,
  2025: 50.7916209335673}}
```

I have plotted the `Historical` column as a line, and I have filled the area between `Policies and action High`, and `Policies and action Low` columns.

The code used is as shown

```
df.Historical.plot(color = "black",
                  lw = 3,
                  label = "Historical")

df["Policies and action High"].plot(color = "skyblue", label = "")
df["Policies and action Low"].plot(color = "skyblue", label = "")
plt.fill_between(x = df.index.tolist(),
                y1 = df["Policies and action Low"],
                y2 = df["Policies and action High"],
                color = "skyblue",
                alpha = 0.25,
                label = "Policies and action")


plt.legend()
```

The resulting plot is as shown:
[image]

Instead of the legend, I'd like to add a filled rectangle of the same color besides the shaded region as shown within the red perimeter, and add corresponding text besides it:

[image]

I am not sure how to add this since this needs to be added outside the boundary of the plot, but still correspond to the figure inside the boundary. How can this be achieved using matplotlib or similar visualisation libraries in Python?

Comment: You can set `clip_on=False` to plot outside the axes bounds: `rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(xy=(2025, 51), width=4, height=1.65, linewidth=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none', clip_on=False); plt.gca().add_patch(rect)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPYsv.png

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion from @tdy I added the following two lines of code to add the rectangle.

```
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(xy=(2026, 50.8),
                                    width=1, height=2,
                                    linewidth=2, edgecolor='skyblue',
                                    alpha = 0.5,
                                    facecolor='skyblue', clip_on= False);

plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
```

To set the rectangle outside the boundary of the plot, I limited the boundary of the x-axis.

```
plt.xlim(2015, 2025.5)
```

And then I added the text using `plt.text()` as shown:

```
plt.text(x = 2027.2, y = 52, s = "Policies and action \n +x°C",)
```

Finally, I get the desired plot as shown below:
[image]